# How to make a reusable component with custom props using tailwind in react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to make my `StarRating` component reusable by sending customized props for color and size to the `Star` component. For example `[#fcc419]`. How can I do that with tailwind?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Star from "./Star";

const StarRating = ({
  maxRating = 5,
  textColor = "black",
  starColor = "black",
  textSize = "xs",
  starSize = 5,
}) => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [tempRating, setTempRating] = useState(0);

  const onRateHandler = (rate) => {
    setRating(rate);
  };
  const onHoverInHandler = (rate) => {
    setTempRating(rate);
  };
  const onHoverOutHandler = () => {
    setTempRating(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className={`flex flex-row justify-center items-center gap-x-4 p-8 `}>
      <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center gap-x-3 ">
        {Array.from({ length: maxRating }, (_, i) => (
          <Star
            key={i}
            onRate={() => onRateHandler(i + 1)}
            full={tempRating ? tempRating >= i + 1 : rating >= i + 1}
            hoverIn={() => onHoverInHandler(i + 1)}
            hoverOut={onHoverOutHandler}
            color={starColor}
            size={starSize}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <p className={`text-${textColor} text-${textSize}`}>
        {tempRating || rating || ""}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StarRating;
```

```
const Star = ({ onRate, full, hoverIn, hoverOut, color, size }) => {
  return (
    <span
      role="button"
      className=" cursor-pointer block "
      onClick={onRate}
      onMouseEnter={hoverIn}
      onMouseLeave={hoverOut}
    >
      {full ? (
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 20 20"
          className={`stroke-${color} fill-${color} w-${size} h-${size} `}
        >
          <path d="M9.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.07 3.292a1 1 0 00.95.69h3.462c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-2.8 2.034a1 1 0 00-.364 1.118l1.07 3.292c.3.921-.755 1.688-1.54 1.118l-2.8-2.034a1 1 0 00-1.175 0l-2.8 2.034c-.784.57-1.838-.197-1.539-1.118l1.07-3.292a1 1 0 00-.364-1.118L2.98 8.72c-.783-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h3.461a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.07-3.292z" />
        </svg>
      ) : (
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 20 20"
          className={`stroke-black fill-none  w-${size} h-${size}`}
        >
          <path
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth="{2}"
            d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"
          />
        </svg>
      )}
    </span>
  );
};

export default Star;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot make any dynamic tailwind classes like this: `` className={`text-${textColor} text-${textSize}`} ``. because tailwind transforms classNames during build time and NOT runtime

so, what you can do is to make an object which includes variants. get the variants by the name whenever you need. like so:

```js
const bgVariants = {
    green: "bg-green-500",
    red: "bg-red-500"
}

const textSizeVariants = {
    small: "text-sm",
    large: "text-lg"
}

const Component: ({textSize, bg, children}) => {
    return (
        <p className={`${bgVariants[bg]} ${textSizeVariants[textSize]}`}>{children}</p>
    )
}
```

and now you can use it:

```js
<Component bg="green" textSize="small" />
<Component bg="red" textSize="large" />
```

this is just the main idea. feel free to implement your own way based on your need